# How to deal when the predictor variable is a proportion in panel data

Tags: r, linear-regression, panel-data

I built a panel data model using the R plm package, where Y is the rate of incarceration, x1 is the proportion of state expenditure on wellfare and x2 is the proportion of state expenditure on security, and z is a vector of control variables. I used the log transformation for Y because it is very skewed. Should I do any transformation on x1 and x2 as these two variables are bounded by 0 and 1?

Comment: This is more for crossvalidated, but you may want to consider a logit link, and maybe a more appropriate error distribution for your model, given that your regressand is a ratio. PLM is essentially transforming data a certain way and running `lm`, which in your case may not be appropriate for your data. Consider the `pglm` package which should allow you to model panel data as if it were logistic regression.

Comment: Thank you very much, Chrisss, your comment was very helpful.